# Insert a floating button on a textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea that I can control over a jquery function to become a full screen one. I would like to add a button to close the fullscreen

my function that manage the fullscreen is :

```
function setFullScreen(cm, full) {
         var wrap = cm.getWrapperElement();
         if (full) {
           wrap.className += " CodeMirror-fullscreen";
           wrap.style.height = winHeight() + "px";
           document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
         } else {
           wrap.className = wrap.className.replace(" CodeMirror-fullscreen", "");
           wrap.style.height = "";
           document.documentElement.style.overflow = "";
         };

        cm.refresh();
       }
```

The way I call it is like this :

**Turn on fullscreen** : `setFullScreen(cm, !isFullScreen(cm));`
**Turn off fullscreen** : `if (isFullScreen(cm)) setFullScreen(cm, false);`

I would like to add a button when my textarea is on fullscreen, I would like that button to be  inside the textarea on the top right corner and independant from scrolling (floating)

Is there a way of doing this using jquery ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position: fixed;` attribute in CSS.  Let's say this is your HTML button mark-up

```
<a href = "#" id = "textarea_close_button">
     <img src = "/img/close_button.png">
</a>
```

Your CSS would look like this:

```
#textarea_close_button{
     position: fixed;
     display: none; //it won't be visible until your textarea becomes fullscreen
     top: 5px;
     right: 5px;
     height: 5px;
     width: 5px;
}
```

Then run the following line of code when you fullscreen your textarea

```
$("#textarea_close_button").css({"display": "block"});
```

And vice-versa when the button is clicked